# Can I make a single collision listener for multiple objects in Corona SDK?

Tags: android, coronasdk

I am making a game that will spawn multiple objects and add them to an array. What I would like to do is have a single listener that will trigger  when collision is detected. I know how to do that with a single object, but how can I create a listener that will work with multiple objects?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, By creating a [Global Collision Handling](https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/physics/collisionDetection/index.html#handling) In order for you to **know** which of the objects **collided** you can add a **tag** on that object example you have three objects:

```
local myObject = {}
--ASSUMING YOU HAVE INITIALIZE THE OBJECTS ALREADY
--SET THE TAG
myObject[0].myName = "object0"    
--DO THE SAME WITH THE OTHER OBJECTS
myObject[1].myName = "object1"
myObject[2].myName = "object2"

--Create your collision function
local function onCollided(event)
    if(event.phase == "began") then
        --BEGAN COLLISION
        --THE BELOW PRINT STATEMENT WILL PRINT WHICH OF THE THREE OBJECTS COLLIDED WITH
        print("Collision Between ".. event.object1.myName .. " and " .. event.object2.myName)
    elseif(event.phase == "ended") then
         --END COLLISION  
    end
end       

--AND OFCOURSE ADD THE LISTENER
Runtime:addEventListener("collision", onCollided)
```

as the **Docs** states that: ***Global collision handling is best utilized in a many-to-many collision scenario***